# Retrieving Workspace in R

Tags: r, ubuntu, workspace

I am working with R on Ubuntu. When I was working I accidentally hit Ctrl-Z and 
it kicked me out of the workspace and I did not save my variables. Is there 
anyway to retrieve my old workspace?

Thank you.

Comment: It is generally best not to save variables: save the source code you use to create the variables instead.  Your analyses will be much more easily reproducible this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jump back into the still-running session via

```
  fg
```

i.e. bring the R session you suspended via `Ctrl-Z` back to the foreground.

Comment: Doesn't work. Says object not found. When I hit Ctrl-Z, it kicked me out of R completely and I was working on the terminal.

Comment: `fg` is a `bash` command which you are supposed to use on the shell command-line.

Comment: Problem again. I was using R in VirtualBox and I put my computer to sleep for the night, leaving everything there. When I came back the next day, VirtualBox was powered off so I had to restart and my entire workspace is gone. Here 'fg' did not work. What should I do?

Comment: You may be out of luck.  As Richie said in his comment to your question:  work from script files -- which allow you re-create your session and variables.  Most editor with support for R (RStudio, or Emacs/ESS, or Eclipse/StatET) permit this easily.

Comment: I was also working with script files. I type my functions in an external editor. It just happens I did not save that file....

Comment: Some editors leave the temporary files behind -- Emacs will write "unsaved" versions of file `foo.bar` into `#foo.bar#`. That has come in handy at times...  But by and large, unless your editor does that, you're now toast and you will have to recreate it.  Save early, save often or use and auto-saving scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Reconnect and try "jobs" from the terminal to see if the R process is still there. If so, `fg` should do the trick as @Dirk said (if you have more than 1 suspended jobs, `fg %2` would bring back the second one etc).

As far as I know, if you actually terminate the R session and did not save your workspace, it is lost - sorry. S-PLUS would save all variables in your workspace directory as you generated them, but R keeps everything in memory until you explicitly save your workspace - typically at exit, but `save.image()` can do it mid-session.

/Tommy

Comment: This is not quite true: one can have an R history saved and the session can be reproduced.

Comment: ...but the R history is only saved when you exit and choose "save workspace", right? So if R crashes, all is lost...

Comment: No, there's a difference between the workspace and the history.  The history is like the history of shell commands - it is a separate file.  I am not sure if it is logged by default, but it presumably depends on one's frontend.  It's often named `.Rhistory`.

Comment: Yeah, I know about .Rhistory. In RGui and Rterm, the history is only saved at exit as far as I know - at the same time as the workspace is saved, so if you say "no" to saving the workspace, the history isn't saved either. Is it different in your frontend? Try killing the R process and see if the history is accurate up to that point.  ..